# vim auto-pairs skip closing double quotes before a word

Tags: vim

I am using vim-autopairs and everytime I type `"` in front of a word it adds the closing double quote before it and I have to press Backspace to delete it. It's so annoying.
How to skip inserting closing double quotes before a word?
It works fine with single quotes `'`.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate). It works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

You can momentarely disable auto-pairs with <kbd>M-p</kbd>

```
<M-p> : Toggle Autopairs (g:AutoPairsShortcutToggle)
```

Comment: I don't understand this snippet plus I don't want to disable the plugin. I want to know if there is a way to fix this bug.

Comment: Alt+p   Toggle Autopairs, type your quote and toggle it back.

Comment: Thanx, but it's too convoluted. I want it to always work as I want it to work, imagine you have 100 of quotes to insert, would like to toggle on off the plugin everytime you type double quotes? Pacepalm